# Unity Buttons with Delays (wait for seconds)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I have 2 buttons, Button 1 & Button 2,
When I click Button 1, Button 1 removes from the screen, and button 2 becomes active. easy. a Simple click event.

However I need button 2, to wait 10 seconds before becoming active on the screen.

So I click button 1, it removes itself, then nothing happens for 10 seconds, then button 2 appears.

I think I need to use in C# WaitForSeconds, however I have no idea how.

I have tried this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

 void Start()
 {
     StartCoroutine(ButtonDelay());
 }

 IEnumerator ButtonDelay()
 {
     print(Time.time);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
     print(Time.time);


 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not start your coroutine in the `Start` instead start your coroutine when the button clicked by adding a listener to your button like this:

```
public Button Button1;
public Button Button2;

void Start() {
    // We are adding a listener so our method will be called when button is clicked
    Button1.onClick.AddListener(Button1Clicked);
}  

void Button1Clicked()
{
    //This method will be called when button1 is clicked 
    //Do whatever button 1 does
    Button1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    StartCoroutine(ButtonDelay());
}

IEnumerator ButtonDelay()
{
    Debug.Log(Time.time);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    Debug.Log(Time.time);

    // This line will be executed after 10 seconds passed
    Button2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Dont forget to drag and drop your buttons to public fields and button2 should not be enabled initially. Good Luck!

Comment: Ali you hero, Thank you So Much